# JavaFX, TableView and setCellFactory

Tags: java, javafx, tableview, frontend

I'm trying to understand better how the `TableView` in **JavaFX** works. 
In order to reach several goals I will try to explain what I did so far, why I did it, and what are my problems.

Of course, I have a `TableView`, which is populated thanks to an `ObservableList`.

```
Platform.runLater(()->ObservableList.add(0, myObject));
```

The Table is composed by 2 columns defined in my **FXML file**, in which I also have:

```
<cellValueFactory><PropertyValueFactory property="column1" /></cellValueFactory>
<cellValueFactory><PropertyValueFactory property="column2" /></cellValueFactory>
```

`MyObject` class, naturally, has these 2 properties and the columns are populated automatically. The first problem I had, was about the strings in the 2nd column (they were too long). That's why I added in my Controller class:

```
@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    setCellFactory();
}

private void setCellFactory() {
    secondColumn.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn, TableCell>() {

        @Override
        public TableCell call(TableColumn param) {
            TableCell cell = new TableCell<>();
            Text text = new Text();
            cell.setGraphic(text);
            cell.setPrefHeight(Control.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE);
            text.wrappingWidthProperty().bind(secondColumn.widthProperty());
            text.textProperty().bind(cell.itemProperty());
            text.setFill(Color.WHITE);
            return cell;
        }
    });
}
```

In that way I solved the problem about the wrapped text but, now, I would like to reach another goal and I really cannot find anything of help on the web.

---

1. For each new entry on the top of the Table, I would like to compare the strings in order to find the differences between them (I already found a library to do that), but I don't know how to find a good way to get the current value in the second column.
2. I have to highlight the differences in the old strings in the table. So, I guess I have to update all old cell. How?
3. Highlight. How to do that? I read it's only possible if I insert several String in the same HBox or something like that. Is there a way to do that in a table?

Comment: Could you explain the *"on the top of the Table"* part in  *"For each new entry on the top of the Table"*? Should this happen for every row or just for the topmost row displayed.

Comment: For every row. I have another field in which I see the last message

Comment: So basically you manually add a new entry with a string and then want to highlight all the differences between the new strings and each of the existing ones?

Comment: Also check out [TextFlow](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/text-settings.htm) for #3 of your questions... You should be able to use that in a custom TableCell.

Comment: @Maverick283 how precisely? I already tried the TextFlow but it doesn't provide methods as wrappingWidthProperty() and textProperty(). That's why I don't know how to create the binding as I did for the Text.

Comment: I just really don't understand what you are trying to do there... But that probably is just me... As for the text flow: did you try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19627679/3653975

Comment: The text should be wrapped inside every cell. My code on the post works for that, but with a TextFlow it doesn't. @Maverick283

Comment: Sorry, wasn't precise enough: I don't understand what you are trying to do in #1. And the link I posted should lead you to a hack on how to wrap TextFlows...

Comment: @Maverick283 Even if the text flow seems to work, the results I get are really strange: the height of each row is too much.

Comment: @Maverick283 about the #1.. it's really simple: I want to read the new value inserted inside my setCellFactory method. If I try something like: param.getCellData(0) I get the String repeated many times

Comment: Hmm can you update your code to what it is now? Slowly running out of answers here... ;) if nothing else works you might wanna throw the table view away and create your own table in a grid view... Not elegant but maybe it will make stuff easier for you. For #1: yeah no, still don't get it... I'm probably too stupid for that ^^ ;)